AWS Lightsail: add SSL to a non-route 53 domain
Is there any way to use HTTPS on a non-route 53 domain used by my Lighsail instance ?
I bought a domain from OVH (french registrar). After that, I've added a record to the OVH DNS zone that redirects domain to my AWS Lightsail instance static IP.
This works for HTTP port 80, but I need to use SSL. I thought I could do this via the Lightsail interface, but I don't see a way. Documentation only suggests it for route 53 domains.
My Lightsail instance hosts a Docker app. I access the app via myDomain.com:3000. Should the SSL certificate be installed from OVH, from the Lightsail instance or from the docker container?

i guess you are uisng ningx or apcache to server you domain, just install cerbot and install certificate for your app thats it

I use Apache in my docker container. Does I need to install Certbot into container ? I'll find out more about Certbot, thank you for your help :)

why sould you serve your app with apache included in your container just let the web proxy run in the instance  proxy pass your container and serve it . people often go for complex setup when not required at all

I believe there's some understanding missing.
DNS is only a table mapping the hostname to IP address (or another hostname). That's it. Nothing more. Nothing to do with SSL. The SSL is part of the transport, it means that must be configured on the sever side.
There are several ways:
Your own SSL reverse proxy
This is more complex setup, yet you have it included in the price of the server.
You can host another docker container on the same server - an http reverse proxy exposing port 443 (SSL).
Examples:

Apache httpd reverse proxy
Nginx reverse proxy

for both you will need to buy and configure the SSL certificate separately. Or you can use a free certificate service (like "Letsencrypt").
AWS Load Balancer
This is what I'd suggest using even it adds some cost to the hosting.
AWS LightSail comes with an ALB (application load balancer) if you enable it. There's a documentation setting up the SSL in the AWS ALB. The ALB is using the AWS Certificate Manager, which takes care of creating and renewing the SSL certificates.
The only thing you need to do is validate the domain ownership. It means when the Certificate Manager is creating new SSL certificates, you have to add some extra DNS records to your hostname provider (OVH) to prove that you manage the domain.

Configuring SSL indeed includes extra components, knowledge and administration, once you get hold of it, you will be reusing the knowledge later, it is worth it

Thank you so much for all these explanations! I'm using Lightsail to temporarily host a Docker app for a few users at a low cost. Isn't using an ALB for a simple SSL a bit oversized, even if it seems easier?

@Loraga from the question it is not clear what scaling do you need. indeed, for simple things for myself I'm usually using a container with SSL proxy and free certificate service (letsencrypt/certbot) to save cost. ALB for customers, where reliability and simple management is priority

Incase it helps someone else, I needed to enable secure 443 for my domain, which is registered elsewhere but with Route 53 NS records.
I edited my original answer.
So Lightsail uses the bitnami stack. In order to setup SSL try the following:

Stop apache sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop apache
Use the bitnami https config tool sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool and follow instructions. You'll need to specify your domain, e.g. www.mydomain.co.uk mydomain.co.uk.

N.B. If you're using Route 53 and have setup a catch-all for your subdomains with *.mydomain.co.uk, then you'll need to specify an additional A record for "www.mydomain.co.uk". This will mess things up if not set up properly as the domains will be pointing to diff IPv4s potentially. E.g. one to Lightsail, and another to EC2 perhaps.
That's all it took for me to setup my cert.
